# Fixed size dynamic grid with Recyclerlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a grid with fixed size but dynamically changing span count (So the cells in the grid will vary in size when the spancount is changed).

What I do not want is:

[image: plus/minus change spancount/itemcount]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- This constrainer view was something I just tested, didn't improve much. And felt hacky (I wanted to have the recyclerview as wrap content) !-->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/constrainer"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constrainer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constrainer"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constrainer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constrainer"
        app:spanCount="3"
        tools:itemCount="9"
        tools:listitem="@layout/MyItem" />
```

And the grid item:

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF00FF00"/>
```

And below is the layoutmanager:

```
    grid.layoutManager = object : GridLayoutManager(this.context, adapter.size){
        override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    }
```

The current setup posted above works in the x dimension, but I can't figure out if I can remove all scrollability and get it working in the Y dimension. I can not get my cells to grow their height correctly.

Am I using the wrong tool(Recyclerview) for the job? How do I best achieve the behaviour I want? (I can probably do Linearlayouts/constraintlayout to make it work, but I imagine there should be an easy way I'm missing)

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a partial self answer, as it works but is not optimal. Will gladly accept an answer which outlines a more proper way to do it.

Resizing the adapter views with the code below in on bind of the adapter:

```
val containerSize = itemView.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.grid_size)
itemView.layoutParams.height = (containerSize / size).toInt()
itemView.layoutParams.width = (containerSize / size).toInt()
```

`size` is row/column-Count. Provides the behaviour I want, (though with some artifacts when `size`does not divide `grid_size` evenly)